# Seg Fault in program when parsing and storing strings in binary tree

Tags: c, parsing, binary-tree

Right now I'm not even getting a seg fault with my program, I'm pretty sure it just runs forever, because when I run the program no output is produced, not even the segmentation fault. Basically what I want my program to do is read in a file of 4 lines. Then we parse the strings using the user created tokenizer function and the already created strtok function. Then I want to make a binary tree out of the commands that are read in. So like I said earlier my program produces no output at the time, but it does compile. I will post the code that I have and the the file that you read in and the sample output. I appreciate the help.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define COMMAND_NAME_LEN 50
#define MAX_SPLIT_SIZE 50
#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE 50

typedef struct Command_ {
    char name[COMMAND_NAME_LEN];
    int expected_param_count;
    struct Command_ *left;
    struct Command_ *right;
}Command;


typedef struct StringArray_ {
    char **strings;
    int size;
}StringArray;

StringArray* tokenizer (char *string, const char* delimiters);
void free_string_array(StringArray *sr);
void create_commands_tree(Command **commands, const char *file);
void insert_into_commands_tree(Command** node, char** data);
Command* get_command(Command *node, const char *command);
Command* create_command(char **data);
void destroy_commands_tree(Command* node);
void display_commands(Command *node);


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) {
            printf("%s is missing commands.dat\n", argv[0]);
            return 0;
    }


    Command* options = NULL;
    create_commands_tree(&options,argv[1]);
    int checking = 1;

    char input_buffer[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];

    do {
            printf("Command: ");
            fgets(input_buffer,MAX_BUFF_SIZE,stdin);
            StringArray* parsed_input = tokenizer(input_buffer," \n");
            Command* c = get_command(options,parsed_input->strings[0]);

            if( c && parsed_input->size == c->expected_param_count) {
                    if (strcmp(c->name, "quit") == 0){
                                    checking = 0;
                    }
                    printf("Valid command used\n");
            }
            else {
                    printf("Invalid command, please try again\n");
            }
            free_string_array(parsed_input);

    }while (checking);

    destroy_commands_tree(options);

}


void create_commands_tree(Command **commands, const char *file) {

    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(file, "r");
    char strings[256];
    Command *temp;
    StringArray *temp2;

    while(fgets(strings,100,input)){

            temp2 = tokenizer(strings, "\n");
            insert_into_commands_tree(&temp,temp2->strings);
    }
}

void insert_into_commands_tree(Command** node, char** data) {

    Command **new_ = node;

    if(node == NULL){
            *new_ = create_command(data);
    }
    else if( new_ != NULL){
            if(strcmp(data[0],(*new_)->name) < 0)
                    insert_into_commands_tree(&(*new_)->left,data);
            else if(strcmp(data[0], (*new_)->name) > 0)
                    insert_into_commands_tree(&(*new_)->right,data);
    }


}

Command* create_command(char **data) {

    Command* new_;
    new_ = (Command*)malloc(sizeof(Command));
    strncpy(new_->name, data[0], COMMAND_NAME_LEN);
    new_->expected_param_count = 0;
    new_->right = NULL;
    new_->left = NULL;


    return new_;

}

Command* get_command(Command *node, const char *command) {

    Command *temp = node;
    int compare;

    if(temp){
            compare = strcmp(node->name, command);
            if(compare == 0){
                    return temp;
            }
            else if(compare < 0){
                    return (get_command(node->right, command));
            }
            else{
                    if(compare > 0){
                            return (get_command(node->left, command));
            }}

    }
   return temp;
}

void destroy_commands_tree(Command* node) {

    if( node == NULL){
            return;
            }

    destroy_commands_tree(node->left);
    destroy_commands_tree(node->right);
    free(node);

}
void display_commands(Command *node) {

      if(node != NULL){
            printf("\npickup <item>");
            printf("\nhelp ");
            printf("\nquit ");
            printf("\nload <file>\n\n");
}
}
 StringArray* tokenizer (char *string, const char* delimiters){

    StringArray *temp = (StringArray*)malloc(sizeof(StringArray));;
    char *split;

    split = strtok(string, delimiters);

    while(split != NULL)
    {
            split = strtok(string, delimiters);
            temp->strings = &split;
    }
    return temp;
}

void free_string_array(StringArray *sr) {

    while(sr != NULL)
            free(sr);

    free(sr);

}
```

Here is the sample output that was given:

```
]$ ./a.out commands.dat 
Command: pickup 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: pickup ball 
Valid command used 
Command: quit 1 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: load 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: load bak.sav 
Valid command used 
Command: help
Valid command used
Command: help 2 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: quit 
Valid command used
```

And the file that we read in is as follows:

```
pickup,2
help,1
quit,1
load,2
```

Comment: please do some debugging and narrow down the problem first.

Comment: the only debugging I know is using gdb. And my program like litterally doesnt run when I use that haha. So i must be screwed

Comment: Can anyone help me or no? I really don't know what to do

Comment: implementation of the tokenizer is bad.