# Parsing a read in file and storing in a b tree

Tags: c, parsing, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I'm pretty sure my program just runs forever, because when I run the program no output is produced, not even the segmentation fault. Basically what I want my program to do is read in a file of 4 lines. Then we parse the strings using the user created tokenizer function and the already created strtok function. Then I want to make a binary tree out of the commands that are read in. So like I said earlier my program produces no output at the time, but it does compile. I will post the code that I have and the the file that you read in and the sample output. I appreciate the help.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define COMMAND_NAME_LEN 50
#define MAX_SPLIT_SIZE 50
#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE 50

typedef struct Command_ {
    char name[COMMAND_NAME_LEN];
    int expected_param_count;
    struct Command_ *left;
    struct Command_ *right;
}Command;


typedef struct StringArray_ {
    char **strings;
    int size;
}StringArray;

StringArray* tokenizer (char *string, const char* delimiters);
void free_string_array(StringArray *sr);
void create_commands_tree(Command **commands, const char *file);
void insert_into_commands_tree(Command** node, char** data);
Command* get_command(Command *node, const char *command);
Command* create_command(char **data);
void destroy_commands_tree(Command* node);
void display_commands(Command *node);


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) {
            printf("%s is missing commands.dat\n", argv[0]);
            return 0;
    }


    Command* options = NULL;
    create_commands_tree(&options,argv[1]);
    int checking = 1;

    char input_buffer[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];

    do {
            printf("Command: ");
            fgets(input_buffer,MAX_BUFF_SIZE,stdin);
            StringArray* parsed_input = tokenizer(input_buffer," \n");
            Command* c = get_command(options,parsed_input->strings[0]);

            if( c && parsed_input->size == c->expected_param_count) {
                    if (strcmp(c->name, "quit") == 0){
                                    checking = 0;
                    }
                    printf("Valid command used\n");
            }
            else {
                    printf("Invalid command, please try again\n");
            }
            free_string_array(parsed_input);

    }while (checking);

    destroy_commands_tree(options);

}


void create_commands_tree(Command **commands, const char *file) {

    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(file, "r");
    char strings[256];
    Command *temp;
    StringArray *temp2;

    while(fgets(strings,100,input)){

            temp2 = tokenizer(strings, "\n");
            insert_into_commands_tree(&temp,temp2->strings);
    }
}

void insert_into_commands_tree(Command** node, char** data) {

    Command **new_ = node;

    if(node == NULL){
            *new_ = create_command(data);
    }
    else if( new_ != NULL){
            if(strcmp(data[0],(*new_)->name) < 0)
                    insert_into_commands_tree(&(*new_)->left,data);
            else if(strcmp(data[0], (*new_)->name) > 0)
                    insert_into_commands_tree(&(*new_)->right,data);
    }


}

Command* create_command(char **data) {

    Command* new_;
    new_ = (Command*)malloc(sizeof(Command));
    strncpy(new_->name, data[0], COMMAND_NAME_LEN);
    new_->expected_param_count = 0;
    new_->right = NULL;
    new_->left = NULL;


    return new_;

}

Command* get_command(Command *node, const char *command) {

    Command *temp = node;
    int compare;

    if(temp){
            compare = strcmp(node->name, command);
            if(compare == 0){
                    return temp;
            }
            else if(compare < 0){
                    return (get_command(node->right, command));
            }
            else{
                    if(compare > 0){
                            return (get_command(node->left, command));
            }}

    }
   return temp;
}

void destroy_commands_tree(Command* node) {

    if( node == NULL){
            return;
            }

    destroy_commands_tree(node->left);
    destroy_commands_tree(node->right);
    free(node);

}
void display_commands(Command *node) {

      if(node != NULL){
            printf("\npickup <item>");
            printf("\nhelp ");
            printf("\nquit ");
            printf("\nload <file>\n\n");
}
}
 StringArray* tokenizer (char *string, const char* delimiters){

    StringArray *temp = (StringArray*)malloc(sizeof(StringArray));;
    char *split;

    split = strtok(string, delimiters);

    while(split != NULL)
    {
            split = strtok(string, delimiters);
            temp->strings = &split;
    }
    return temp;
}

void free_string_array(StringArray *sr) {

    while(sr != NULL)
            free(sr);

    free(sr);

}
```

Here is the sample output that was given:

```
]$ ./a.out commands.dat 
Command: pickup 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: pickup ball 
Valid command used 
Command: quit 1 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: load 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: load bak.sav 
Valid command used 
Command: help
Valid command used
Command: help 2 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: quit 
Valid command used
```

And the file that we read in is as follows:

```
pickup,2
help,1
quit,1
load,2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Seg Fault in program when parsing and storing strings in binary tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869618/seg-fault-in-program-when-parsing-and-storing-strings-in-binary-tree)

Comment: You might consider trying to improve your original question rather than trying to repost it.

Comment: No one responded to my old one and someone responded to this one and helped me so id say it was worth it

Comment: While you might feel it was a good idea this time, it isn't a good pattern to fall into.  You might read through [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions) for the proper way to try and draw attention to your questions.  The best way is to ask a good question in the first place.  There is plenty of advice in the help center about that.

Answer (score 0):

From the strtok manpage:

```
   The strtok() function breaks a string into a sequence of zero or more nonempty tokens.  On the
   first call to strtok() the string to be parsed should be specified in str.  In each subsequent
   call that should parse the same string, str must be NULL.
```

Your tokenizer is not using strtok correctly.  Your code is stuck in the while loop.